# Automatically generated password after registering

Tags: wordpress

how i can generate password with email new user registration?

1) User insert e-mail
2) wordpress send email with autogenerate password

Comment: will you have your own register form or use the one provided by wordpress?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's function, **wp_new_user_notification** You can write this and it will work.

```
wp_new_user_notification( $user_id, $random_password);
```